# What are possible values for --rawvid-chroma

Tags: vlc

I'm trying to see if I can play back nv12 .yuv files through VLC. I see there is a switch called --rawvid-chroma. "nv12" doesn't seem to work, but "I420" does. I'm curious as to what are some valid strings for --rawvid-chroma

Comment: NV12 is actually identical to I420, you could have used that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This videolan [wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Chroma/) page looks like it might be a list of possible VLC chroma values. It includes YUYV which I know works and I420 but doesn't include NV12.

RV24 and RV32 look like they could be 24bit and 32bit RGB.